# Export 'Final' output of ExampleStreaming from Watson Unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to export the 'Final' result of Speech to text from Watson Unity SDK's ExampleStreaming script.

I'm trying to append it with a CSV output of another SDK(Affectiva).
What is the best way to ensure I capture just the final output + timestamp of the ResultsField and not the Interim responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SpeechRecognitionResult](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/1d626fbb1a4c2ac327c377e0222263efc9ed7a0a/Scripts/Services/SpeechToText/v1/DataModels.cs#L185) has a `final` property. You can look for this bool value and only save final results. From [ExampleStreaming.cs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/1d626fbb1a4c2ac327c377e0222263efc9ed7a0a/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs#L214).

```
private void OnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    if (result != null && result.results.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var res in result.results)
        {
            foreach (var alt in res.alternatives)
            {
                if (res.final)
                {
                    //  do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```